# what's the correct sql UNION in android?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

```
(SELECT word, description 
FROM dictionary
WHERE word LIKE 'xxxx%') AS a

UNION

(SELECT word, description
FROM dictionary
WHERE word LIKE '%xxxx%' AND word NOT IN a.word)
```

note: the "xxxxx" is the keyword.

I'm working a dictionary application on Android which search through keyword. 
The requirement is to put those result starting with the keyword on top. 
I come up with the idea of union by sql but I'm not a SQL expert so can someone help me figure out what I have done wrong with the above query.

FYI: I'm using rawQuery() which process the raw SQL statement.

Thanks to community.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no guarantee that the `UNION` operator will order the rows from the two subqueries in the order you assume. `UNION ALL` does not try to find duplicates so it has more chances to work (as you hope to).

So this may work (or it may not!) - depending on how `UNION ALL` works internally:

```
(SELECT word, description 
FROM dictionary
WHERE word LIKE 'xxxx%') AS a

UNION ALL

(SELECT word, description
FROM dictionary
WHERE word LIKE '%_xxxx%') AS b
```

---

It's better to explicitedly specify the order with `ORDER BY`. I think that SQLite supports this:

```
SELECT word, description
FROM dictionary
WHERE word LIKE '%xxxx%'
ORDER BY (word LIKE 'xxxx%') DESC
```

Comment: Thanks ypercube, your answer's save my life. :)